# MySQL relation without using foreign key references

Tags: php, mysql

I have question about making relation between two tables in mysql. I create table with column which is foreign key, but I dont use foreign key references keyword. I connect tables in code(php/asp.net). I dont know if it is good habit? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tag properly!  If this is php, why do I see `asp.net-mvc` tag on your question?

Comment: If it's a foreign key column, why wouldn't you want to link the tables?

Comment: Foreign key constraints enforce referential integrity.

Comment: I link tables in code. I want to know if it is good habit or I shound not do it like that. Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can continue linking your data in code for however you are using it, but you should add a foreign key constraint in your database so a flawed update, delete, or insert doesn't result in your data losing it's integrity in the future.

Databases that lack foreign key constraints on foreign keys often times have orphans that should never exist show up, especially when you have multiple developers working within the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally seen as a good habit to create a foreign key constraint as it will **enforce** data integrity between the two columns.

Yes, you can have 100% valid data in your database without using any foreign key constraints at all, but implementing them will make it impossible for a flawed update, delete, or insert to violate the foreign constraint between them in the future.